# Connect internal CRT's RGB to external LCD

Tags: output, interface, video

In my boat i have a sonar with CRT monitor and no external video output. I would like to connect a LCD monitor instead. Schematic below show the RGB signals internally.

[image]

Reg pic. My question is: If and where can I solder cables into the PCB and use as output for a LCD monitor?

New better picture?

[image]

Comment: From the little information you've given us, I don't think it's possible to answer your question.  I can't even tell if that connector is an input or an output.

Comment: Internal video connections may not have used a standard format. And if they did, there are several. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_video  This is not an easy task.

Comment: A general observation: In this old schematic, there's a thick line that other lines crosses (shown with small circles), does it represent a shield or barrier of some kind?

Comment: @MiNiMe: I suspect that those lines indicate PC boards - the components driving the CRT are inside one such line and would be on one PC board, while everythiing else is inside another line and would be on another board.

Comment: There is no specs for the RGB lines. So it may be incompatible voltage leves with your external LCD, of which we also don't know the specs. Even if th RGB lines were electrically compatible, the next problem is the Sync wire. No specs of it, no specs of LCD. Even if it were electrically compatible, next problem is if the video format is compatible or not. No specs again.

Comment: The pins you show with RGB and sync are inputs to drive the CRT. Where do those signal come from?